# Can anyone explain these inaccuracies with MKMapView::mapRectThatFits

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, mapkit

I am getting strange inaccuracies when using MKMapView::mapRectThatFits. If I pass in an MKMapRect that is wider than it is higher I would expect mapRectThatFits to return a new MapRect with the same horizontal span, but with increased vertical span to fit it into the mapView, however I am noticing MKMapView adding to the horizontal span as well as the vertical.

[image]

This inaccuracy seems to increase as the coordinate region increases in dimensions. At a few hundred meters the accuracy is negligible, but at a 1.5 kilometers, the difference is 0.0006  which is significant.

I have tried using mapRectThatFits:edgePadding with edge padding set to zero and regionThatFits but both result in the same inaccuracies.

```
MKCoordinateRegion combinedRegion = self.models.locationModelsCoordinator.coordinateRegion;
NSLog(@"Before %f", combinedRegion.center.longitude - (combinedRegion.span.longitudeDelta * 0.5)); // Logs -0.103473

MKMapRect combinedRect = [ELMapKitUtils mapRectForCoordinateRegion:combinedRegion];
// If I convert combinedRect back to an MKCoordinateRegion here I can verify it is unaltered, so there is no issue with my conversion code.
MKMapRect focusRect = [self.mapView mapRectThatFits:combinedRect];

MKCoordinateRegion regionFittedToMapView = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(focusRect);
NSLog(@"After %f", regionFittedToMapView.center.longitude - (regionFittedToMapView.span.longitudeDelta * 0.5)); // Logs -0.104107
```

Comment: I saw this under iOS 5, but under iOS 6 it's gone with the new Apple maps.

Comment: I think that @CyrilGodefroy's answer is correct. It is no longer an issue because they are using vectors that don't need to be forced to display at specific sizes. Now all you need to worry about is that Apple Maps are about as accurate as a map drawn by a dog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have bitmap tiles. MapKit today adapts to the full size of the bitmap tiles, showing horizontally wider area because of that. If MapKit did use vector based tiles, which it might do in a future version, as demonstrated yesterday during the Keynote, it wouldn't be limited by that bitmap tiles issue.

There is no workaround today with MapKit. I didn't look at bing Maps or Routeme. You should.